# Specifying bounds for one dimensional optimization problem SciPy

Tags: python, python-3.x, optimization, scipy

I have a one dimensional function that I need to optimize. My initial value is 20 and bounds is `(0,50)`

- `x0=[20]`
- `bounds=(0,50)`
- `sol1=minimize(f,x0,method="SLSQP",bounds=bounds)`

However, this produces an IndexError.

`SLSQP Error: the length of bounds is not compatible with that of x0.`

What mistake am I making here?

Comment: `bounds=[(0,20)]` ?

Comment: Additionally, you probably should use `minimize_scalar`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments, you can just put the bounds in a list. A minimal example would look like this:

```
from scipy.optimize import minimize


def f(x):
    return (x - 3) ** 2

x0 = [10]
bounds = [(0, 50)]

res = minimize(f, x0, method='SLSQP', bounds=bounds)
```

Then `res.x` will give the expected `array([3.])`.

As pointed out by @sascha in the comments, for this kind of problem you can also use [`minimize_scalar`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.minimize_scalar.html#scipy.optimize.minimize_scalar):

Just change the import above to

```
from scipy.optimize import minimize_scalar
```

and use

```
res2 = minimize_scalar(f, method='bounded', bounds=bounds)
```

Then `res2.x` returns `3.0`

Just replace `f` above by your actual function.